# Is it possible to detect Power Nap / DarkWake mode in OSX

Tags: macos, launchd, power-management

I have a daemon process started via launchd. This will be running even during DarkWake and has no time to finish before OS X goes back to sleep again.

I can think of the following solutions, but didn't find a way to achieve this.

1. Don't make this daemon process run during DarkWake.

   I went through Apple documentation and forums but didn't find any reference for this.
2. During DarkWake via daemon process make the OS wait until its done.

   Tried with calling pmset noidle and caffeinate in daemon process. It didn't work. OS X went to sleep. It seems OS X suppresses the delivery of many notifications when in DarkWake mode.
3. Detect DarkWake mode in daemon process.

   Didnt find any solution/method to detect DarkWake mode.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe try looking at some of these `sysctl -a | grep -iE "dark|wake"` ... `kern.wakereason` and `debug.darkwake: 3`

Comment: Mark Setchell, thank you for the quick response. kern.wakereason can be RTC, but it can be from scheduler / DarkWake right? We can't be sure that it is from DarkWake here, can we? What is the significance of  debug.darkwake.

Comment: I don't know! It wasn't a full answer, just a comment that I hoped might help you get started.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: I wonder too. @user12345 ?

Comment: One approach is to detect it indirectly, relying on the fact that when in darkwake state there shouldn't be any active display. Alternatively, if this is a laptopt you can detect lid-close. The linked question (rhs sidebar) shows you how you might do this, or you can do it more programatically via CoreGraphics APIs.

There almost surely is some private iopm function that will allow you to do this but you'd need to dig through the source a bit (all of this components are open-sourced).

Comment: As to how you can convert a darkwake into an actual wake, you want the UserIsActive assertion. However normally when lid is closed on laptop it overrides such an assertion, so the system will fall back into darkwake. You can override this via AppliesOnLidClose property (needs entitlement on 10.13+ though, `pmset -b disablesleep 1` is a workaround. See https://github.com/iccir/Fermata)

Comment: You can use it like 

```
  IOReturn err = kIOReturnSuccess;
  
  IOPMAssertionID assertionID = 0;
  if (!err) err = IOPMAssertionCreateWithDescription(CFSTR("UserIsActive"),
       CFSTR("MY CUSTOM APP"), CFSTR("MY APP PREVENTING SLEEP"),
       NULL, NULL,
       (CFTimeInterval)5*60, kIOPMAssertionTimeoutActionRelease,
       &assertionID);
  if (!err) err = IOPMAssertionSetProperty(assertionID, CFSTR("AppliesOnLidClose"), kCFBooleanTrue);
  sleep(5*60);
```

which should convert a darkwake to an actual wake, or prevent falling into darkwake even with screen closed.

Comment: Found it, use `IOPMIsADarkWake(IOPMConnectionGetSystemCapabilities());`

See https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1179.40.20/pwr_mgt.subproj/IOPMLibPrivate.h.auto.html and https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-59754.100.106/OSX/authd/server.c.auto.html for reference

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to find out about these wakes too.
Using the `log` utility, I can see these lines when the system wakes up on its own (even without powernap activated):

2019-04-11 22:18:00.622600+0200 0x250      Default     0x0                  83     0    powerd: [powerd:sleepWake] vm.darkwake_mode: 1 -> 1

2019-04-11 22:18:00.625413+0200 0x250      Default     0x0                  83     0    powerd: [powerd:sleepWake] DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] due to RTC/Maintenance:

In order to detect this, something like this should work:

```
log show --last 1m --predicate 'subsystem == "powerd"' | grep "DarkWake from Deep Idle"
```

Alternatively, using caffeinate in your script might work too (haven't tested this yet).